# Unable to read from port ttyACM* after restart

Tags: 18.04, udev, serial-port, arduino

I have a Teensyduino thermal sensor its working fine in windows but when i connect it to linux either with ubuntu or centos. I didn't get the reading from specified port then i added a rules 49-teensy.rules from [Teensyduino](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/49-teensy.rules)

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0483", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1", ENV{ID_MM_PORT_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0483", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0483", MODE:="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0483", MODE:="0666"
```

and trigger the changes with command

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

It work fine. When i restart the machine it stop working. Please help me how to fix it.

Comment: Do the rules trigger when you plug the USB in while the system is running? Did you write the rules yourself? If yes, please explain the intention behind each rule. If not, please [edit] your question and add a link to the site where you found them.

Comment: @danzel after reloading the rules when i plug in it work but after restarting it doesn't work